# Mysql driver instead of hsql driver for Solr 8.5.2

Tags: solr, solr8, solr8.4.1

Can we use `dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"` instead of `dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"` as specified in [Solr 8.5 document for Data Import Handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#configuring-the-dih-configuration-file)?

If yes, can you please share me `db-data-config.xml` having mysql driver?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. What isn't working? You'll have to use an `url` format that matches what the MySQL JDBC driver expects, i.e. something like `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"`

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, I did the required changes for MySQL jdbc driver with proper driver name, url, username and password in `data-config.xml`. Mistake seems to be from `solrconfig.xml`, since its throwing error `The solrconfig.xml file for this index does not have an operational DataImportHandler defined!`

Comment: You linked to the part below how you define your data import handler in `solrconfig.xml` in the reference guide - have you done that part to define the data import handler?

Comment: @MatsLindh I had to change mysql driver to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` in `data-config.xml` and since data was not getting indexed, I had to remove `add-schema-fields` in `update.autoCreateFields` property. This solved the problem and now its working. Thanks for the help @MatsLindh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem for me-

- Change mysql driver name to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` in
  `data-config.xml`. Default we have `driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`
- Remove `add-schema-fields` in `update.autoCreateFields` property.